# Clearing GPU RAM after image generation using StableDiffusionPipeline in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use StableDiffusionPipeline (diffusers). The code successfully creates images, but afterward, the GPU RAM is not getting cleared. How can I clean the GPU RAM?

```
def create(prompt, negative_prompt, steps, scale, num_images_per_prompt, seed, width, height):
    
    
    model_id = "SG161222/Realistic_Vision_V2.0"
    device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
    # Use the Euler scheduler here instead
    scheduler = EulerDiscreteScheduler.from_pretrained(
        model_id, subfolder="scheduler")
    pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
        model_id,torch_dtype=torch.float16)
    pipe = pipe.to(device)

    DIR_NAME="../output/"
    dirpath = Path(DIR_NAME)
    # create parent dir if doesn't exist
    dirpath.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    prompt_ = prompt
    negative_prompt_ = negative_prompt
    steps_ = int(steps)
    scale_ = float(scale)
    width_ = int(width)
    height_ = int(height)
    num_images_per_prompt_ = int(num_images_per_prompt)
    seed_ = int(seed, 16)
    if seed_ == -1:
        seed_ = torch.randint(0, 1000000, (1,)).item()

    generator = torch.Generator(device=device).manual_seed(seed_)

    output = pipe(prompt_, negative_prompt=negative_prompt_, width=width_, height=height_, num_inference_steps=steps_,
                guidance_scale=scale_, num_images_per_prompt=num_images_per_prompt_, generator=generator)

        
    for idx, image in enumerate(output.images):
        current_GMT = time.gmtime()
        time_stamp = calendar.timegm(current_GMT)
        image_name = str(time_stamp) + " - " + str(idx) +".png"
        image_path = dirpath / image_name
        image.save(image_path)
        print(idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create(prompt, negative_prompt, steps, scale, num_images_per_prompt, seed, width, height):
        
    model_id = "SG161222/Realistic_Vision_V2.0"
    device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
    # Use the Euler scheduler here instead
    scheduler = EulerDiscreteScheduler.from_pretrained(
        model_id, subfolder="scheduler")
    pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
        model_id,torch_dtype=torch.float16)
    pipe = pipe.to(device)

    DIR_NAME="../output/"
    dirpath = Path(DIR_NAME)
    # create parent dir if doesn't exist
    dirpath.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    prompt_ = prompt
    negative_prompt_ = negative_prompt
    steps_ = int(steps)
    scale_ = float(scale)
    width_ = int(width)
    height_ = int(height)
    num_images_per_prompt_ = int(num_images_per_prompt)
    seed_ = int(seed, 16)
    if seed_ == -1:
        seed_ = torch.randint(0, 1000000, (1,)).item()

    generator = torch.Generator(device=device).manual_seed(seed_)

    output = pipe(prompt_, negative_prompt=negative_prompt_, width=width_, height=height_, num_inference_steps=steps_,
                guidance_scale=scale_, num_images_per_prompt=num_images_per_prompt_, generator=generator)
        
    for idx, image in enumerate(output.images):
        current_GMT = time.gmtime()
        time_stamp = calendar.timegm(current_GMT)
        image_name = str(time_stamp) + " - " + str(idx) +".png"
        image_path = dirpath / image_name
        image.save(image_path)
        print(idx)

    #here torch.cuda.empty_cache()    

#or here, based on what you intend to do: torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```